# Instagram cached version

Tags: caching, instagram, archive

I was wondering if there was a way to see the cached view of an instagram profile? I tried using http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:URL but it turns out when redirecting the page it goes to the "search" profile on instagram.  I also tried many other known websites, but with no success. Any help is appreciated, thank you!